# length converter android studio

Tags: java, android, unit-conversion

I am trying to make a length converter app and my confusion is how do I get my work done to convert from one unit to another unit using two spinners and a calculate button? The issue I have is that I cannot figure out how to convert the unit in the drop down list from one spinner to another unit in the second spinner. I also need to display the answer after the user enters the number and picks the units from the list.

**This is my layout file of my main activity**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.unitconverter.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="WEIGHT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick=""
    android:layout_below="@+id/lengthButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lengthButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lengthButton"
    android:id="@+id/weightButton"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:text="LENGTH"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lengthButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:text="Unit Converter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="VOLUME"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/volumeButton"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/weightButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weightButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/weightButton" />

<Button
    android:text="TEMPERATURE"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/temperatureButton"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/volumeButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**This is the java portion of my main activity**

```
         public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Button lengthbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lengthButton);

        lengthbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, lengthActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Button weightbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weightButton);

        weightbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, weightActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Button volumebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.volumeButton);

        volumebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,volumeActivity.class));
            }
        });

        Button temperaturebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.temperatureButton);

        temperaturebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,temperatureActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**This is my length layout file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_length"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.unitconverter.lengthActivity">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/lengthList2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/convertToTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/convertToTextView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/convertToTextView" />

<TextView
    android:text="Length Converter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:id="@+id/lengthTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lengthList2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lengthList2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lengthList2"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:text="Result "
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lengthList2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lengthList2" />

<TextView
    android:text="Convert to:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:id="@+id/convertToTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/convertEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/convertEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/convertEditText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Convert from"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/convertEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lengthTextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lengthTextView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lengthTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/lengthList"
    android:id="@+id/lengthList"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/convertEditText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**This is what I have for my main activity length file. Can anyone please help me?**

```
public class lengthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (saved Instance State);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_length);

        final Spinner group = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.lengthList);
        final Spinner group2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.lengthList2);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final TextView result = ((TextView) 



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Obviously, your code would have to fetch numerical values from your UI controls; then determine what kind of conversion is asked for; make the computations and then display the result. Do you really expect us to dig into all your existing stuff to figure what is missing on your end to get there?

Comment: You need a selection listener on the spinner to know what you selected.

Comment: I just need a idea of what I need in my main activity length file.

Answer (score 0):

hello i have created a length converter.. i hope it helps

```
//java file

public class LengthConverter{

EditText val;
TextView ans, ftv;
Spinner from, to;
Integer positionFrom, positionTO, res;
Button convert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_length_converter);

    val = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    ans = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Answer);

    from = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFrom);
    to = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTo);

    convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.convert);


//        positionFrom = from.getSelectedItemPosition();
//        positionTO = to.getSelectedItemPosition();


    List<String> unitlength = new ArrayList<String>();

    unitlength.add("Meter");
    unitlength.add("Centimeter");
    unitlength.add("Kilometer");
    unitlength.add("Miles");
    unitlength.add("Foot");
    unitlength.add("Inches");
    unitlength.add("Yard");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, unitlength);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    from.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> unit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, unitlength);
    unit.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    to.setAdapter(unit);

    from.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    to.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            method(v);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    switch (parent.getId())
    {
        case R.id.SpinnerFrom:
            from.setSelection(position);
            positionFrom = from.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Log.e("from selected position:", String.valueOf(positionFrom));
            break;

        case R.id.SpinnerTo:
            to.setSelection(position);
            positionTO = to.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Log.e("to selected position:", String.valueOf(positionTO));
            break;
    }

}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public void method(View view)
{

     double value =  Double.parseDouble(val.getText().toString());
     double res;
     double hun = 100;

    Log.e("from value in method", String.valueOf(positionFrom));

    if (positionFrom == 0)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");
        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            res = value * hun;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            res = value * 1000;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {
            res = value * 0.000621371;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            res = value * 3.28084;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            res = value * 39.3701;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            res = value * 1.09361;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }
    }

    if (positionFrom == 1)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            res = value / 100;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            res = value / 10000;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {
            res = value * 6.2137e-6;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            res = value * 0.0328084;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            res = value * 0.393701;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            res = value * 0.0109361;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }
    }

    if ( positionFrom == 2)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            res = value * 1000;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            res = value * 100000;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");
        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {
            res = value * 0.621371;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            res = value * 3280.84;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            res = value * 39370.1;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            res = value * 1093.61;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }
    }

    if (positionFrom == 3)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            res = value * 1609.34;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            res = value * 160934;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            res = value * 1.60934;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");
        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            res = value * 5280;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            res = value * 63360 ;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            res = value * 1760;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }
    }

    if (positionFrom == 4)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            res = value * 0.3048;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            res = value * 30.48;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            res = value * 0.0003048;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {

            res = value * 0.000189394;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            res = value * 12 ;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            res = value * 0.333333;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }
    }

    if (positionFrom == 5)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            res = value * 0.0254;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            res = value * 2.54;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            res = value * 2.54e-5;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {
            res = value * 1.5783e-5;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            res = value * 0.0833333 ;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");

        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            res = value * 0.0277778;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }
    }

    if (positionFrom == 6)
    {
        if (positionTO == 0)
        {
            res = value * 0.9144;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 1)
        {
            res = value * 91.44;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 2)
        {
            res = value * 0.0009144;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 3)
        {

            res = value * 0.000568182;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));

        }

        if (positionTO == 4)
        {
            res = value * 3;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 5)
        {
            res = value * 36 ;
            ans.setText(Double.toString(res));
        }

        if (positionTO == 6)
        {
            val.setText("");
            ans.setText("");

        }
    }

}

}
```